# how should you pass a context to a named function using jQuery .on?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function I need to call from a few different places, the function runs after clicking an 'a' tag or from a submit event, and in all three instances I need to preventDefault but I get the error 'cannot preventDefault of undefined'.

```
$('a#Link').on('click', supaFunc);

function supaFunc(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // do all the things...

}
```

Had a look at the documentation but I haven't solved it.  I'm sure its to do with context, and I can make this work buy calling an anonymous function in the .on method that works fine, but I'd prefer not repeat this function three times.

Comment: That should work just fine -> **http://jsfiddle.net/7Ey2D/**

Comment: @IsabelHM — That will call the function **immediately** instead of binding it as an event handler.

Comment: [See this](http://jsfiddle.net/j63r8/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery event handlers should always receive the event as their first argument. If it's undefined, I would suspect that you call the handler in a different fashion at some place.

To find out where and how, try changing the code to

```
function supaFunc(e) {
    if (typeof e === 'undefined') {
      debugger;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Now, when the function is called without an argument, the debugger will kick in.

Open the developer tools of your browser and reload / run the page. When the problem occurs, follow the call stack downwards until you find the location where `supaFunc` was called without an event as an argument.

[image]

Example image of the Chrome Developer Tools debugger.

Comment: thanks for the extra effort, but realized I was just being silly and calling this when there was no event somewhere else as you suggested.   So I suppose the real answer is that the context is passed when using .on  - just don't code stupid and then look for overly complex answers to really simple problems.

Answer (score 0):

May be `<a id="link"></a>` does not exist in all three cases, the error seems point to that.

Comment: it definitely does exist, as its triggering the event.